# How to views all documents in a particular collection of database in MongoDB through mongo Shell?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.4

In the MongoDB shell, how to views all documents in a particular collection for the current database that I'm using?

when i am trying through the query

```
> db.getCollection().find()
```

To getting the error as mention below

```
2017-10-14T00:57:34.363+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: collection constructor called with undefined argument :
DB.prototype.getCollection@src/mongo/shell/db.js:34:16
@(shell):1:1
```

I am also uploading the screen shot of mongo shell command prompt here

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OK, let's start from basics!

After you have connected to mongod with command `mongo`.

- List databases with command `show dbs`

`iot:PRIMARY> show dbs
    admin  0.000GB 
    iot    0.020GB 
    local  0.042GB
    test   0.000GB 
    testi  0.000GB`

- Select one of the DB's with `use iot` command

`iot:PRIMARY> use iot`

`switched to db iot`

- List collections on that DB with `show collections` command

`iot:PRIMARY> show collections
data
header
key`

- Make query to one of those collections

`iot:PRIMARY> db.header.find()
{ "_id" : "1b5caa", "temp1" : "Temperature", "pressure1" : "Pressure", "humidity1" : "Humidity", "uv1" : "UV", "BusV1" : "Solar Panel (V)", "Current1" : "Solar Panel Current (mA)", "BusV2" : "Battery (V)", "Current2" : "Battery Current (mA)" }
{ "_id" : "30444", "temp1" : "Temperature", "pressure1" : "Pressure", "humidity1" : "Humidity" }
{ "_id" : "239684", "temp1" : "Temperature", "pressure1" : "Pressure", "humidity1" : "Humidity" }`

So, you need to be connected WANTED database with `use` command and you need to show the one collection what you want to query with `db.<collection_name>.find()`

How to see to what database I'm connected currently? Just give command `db` and you get the answer what is your current DB.

Comment: Yes JJussi through db.<collection_name>.find(), i am able to find out all documents in a particular collection. Even db.getCollection('Document Name').find({}), also able to get the complete documents in a particular collection. so, i am going to a accept as a answer.

Comment: Very good explanation for a beginner <3

Answer (score 5):

Ref:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/

Select All Documents in a Collection

To select all documents in the collection, pass an empty document as the query filter parameter to the find method. The query filter parameter determines the select criteria:

```
db.inventory.find( {} )
```

These operation corresponds to the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM inventory
```

Comment: unable to find out through your query db.inventory.find( {} ). Even i have gone through the mention ref mongo documents, but not find out the exact my query desire.thanks

Comment: Your query is wrong. it is `dbname.collectionName.find( {} )` . Why are you using `getcollection()`?

Comment: ,ok. Why are you using getcollection()? What do you mean by that? in respect of mongo shell query or else

Comment: To find all documents in a collection the command is `dbname.collectionname.find( {}  )`

Comment: As per your instruction when i am running the query like dbname.collectionname.find( {} ) then getting the error such as
2017-10-14T01:26:59.230+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] ReferenceError: collectionname is not defined :
@(shell):1:1

Comment: Do you have that collection? Make sure the you are using correct collection name.

Comment: yes i am using the correct name of the collection.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67089/discussion-between-sqlworldwide-and-md-haidar-ali-khan).

Comment: ,Thanks for your support through this query statement db.getCollection('Document Name').find({}) . I am able to fetch all documents in a particular collection. If i am not mentioning 'document name' as a parameter in 'getCollection' method then i am not able to fetch the all documents records. But when i am using as a 'document name' is  as a parameter in 'getCollection' method along with find({}) then   getting all documents in my particular collection.

Comment: ' 
To find all documents in a collection the command is dbname.collectionname.find( {} ). Here we have missed the db.getCollection('documentname').find({}). For this logic suggestion +1

Answer (score 1):

First choose the database: `use <database_name>`

Show out all collections: `show collections`   OR    `db.getCollectionNames()`

Show all documents:  `db.<collection_name>.find()`

Show all document in easy-to-read and attractive format: `db.<collection_name>.find().pretty`

Answer (score -1):

```
show dbs
```

use your database name
in my case, I'm using - `use smartbank`
then - `show collections` - just to check the document collections name.
and finally, `db.` your collection name`.find()` or `find({})` -

```
db.users.find() or db.users.find({}) or db.users.find({_id: ObjectId("60c8823cbe9c1c21604f642b")})
```

you can specify `_id:ObjectId`(write the document id here) to get the single document

[image]

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to add much to the earlier answers.